# Obtener una variable aleatoria

Tags: javascript

Como puedo *obtener una variable aleatoria* , teniendo una serie de estas:

```
var a = 'HFKDJ3';
var b = 'JFI393';
var c = 'KMMMFN';
```

Como puedo mostrar por `document.write` cualquiera de esas variables, pero ***aleatoriamente,***

Comment: ¿Estás usando `Math.random()`? Creo que olvidaste incluir un __[mcve]__.

Comment: Mételas en un arreglo, y luego has el clásico `Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes meterlas en un arreglo y hacer el clásico `Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)`

```js
var a = 'HFKDJ3';
var b = 'JFI393';
var c = 'KMMMFN';

var arr = [a,b,c];

console.log(arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]);
```

Comment: Gracias Lixus ;)

Answer (score 4):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo en el que:

Creo un array textos con los 3 textos.
Al pulsar el botón llamo a la función aleatorio que calcula un nº aleatorio entre 0 y 2 y devuelve el texto correspondiente.
Muestra un alert con el texto devuelto.

EDITO

Modifico el código para utilizar objetos de forma que la función no sólo devuelva el texto si no también la clave del valor seleccionado.

```js
var textos = [
  {key: 'a', value: 'HFKDJ3'}, 
  {key: 'b', value: 'JFI393'}, 
  {key: 'c', value: 'KMMMFN'}
];

function aleatorio(){
  var indice = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));
  var el = textos[indice];
  return el.key + ': ' + el.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="aleatorio" onclick="alert(aleatorio());" />
```

Comment: Perfecto, pero si quisiera obtener el nombre de la variable que salió seleccionada?

Comment: Lo mejor sería utilizar objetos con diferentes propiedades. He modificado el ejemplo para mostrar  cómo hacerlo