# Acceder a propiedades de objeto prototipo

Tags: javascript

Como se ***UTILIZA*** el prototipo de un objeto para ser usado en otros?:

Teniendo este prototipo:

```
 Estadio.prototype {

    Utilidad: 'Fútbol',
    PastoSintetico: true

    }
```

***Mis problemas son:***

> 1) A propiedad y método común se refiere a los que todos tendran por
>   ende solo debo especificarlos en el prototype ?
>
> 2) Como podría crear 2 objetos con estas propiedades en comunes y
>   tambíen con sus propias propiedades y metodos? **Mi intento fué**:

```
 function Estadio1(nombre, capacidad) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.capacidad = capacidad;

    }
function Estadio2(nombre, capacidad) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.capacidad = capacidad;

    }
```

3) Al crear estos 3 objetos nuevos, y quiero usar todas sus propiedades incluyendo obviamente las del prototipo es solamente llamar al objeto creado con prototype?, ***osea esto(según mi entendimiento):***

`Estadio1.prototype.utilidad`

> o

`Estadio1.utilidad` ?

> 4) Se pueden añadir propiedades a los prototipos?
>
> 5) Alguna manera más de crear prototipos?

Comment: [Te la ponen en espera](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68559/como-funciona-el-prototipo-de-un-objeto) y la vuelves a formular? Está en proceso de reapertura, un poco de paciencia :/ Además tienes [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68390/obtener-una-variable-aleatoria) sin aceptar respuesta ....

Comment: este es un tema relacionado, pero diferente y específico.

Comment: @EduardoSebastian, veo que esta pregunta es exactamente igual a [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68559/como-funciona-el-prototipo-de-un-objeto). Lo único que tienen de diferente es el título. ¿Por qué piensas que estas dos preguntas son diferentes si haces las mismas preguntas en ellas?

Comment: la pregunta anterior era diferente y la edité, pero la dejaron en espera y perdió importancia, asi que prefiero hacer la reformulación ordenada, detallada y específica en un nuevo post, y además la otra quedaría probablemente sin atención.